# Android Custom Adapter generate blank screen and position always 0

Tags: android, gridview, listadapter

Please help, so when I created hard coded String array, it displays in a gridview.  So I created a class called movie to store movie titles and movie poster url path to get the image.  When I run the app I get a blank screen.  The following attachment is my adapter code, where when I debug, I check the data list and values I'm getting is correct.  The movie title along with the poster image path.  The position for the list adapter is always stuck on 0.  Please let me know if this is sufficient, if not i can also post my main activity code.

```
public class MovieListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public Context mContext;
    public ArrayList<Movie> malAdapterMoviesList;

    public MovieListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.malAdapterMoviesList = movies;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return malAdapterMoviesList.size(); }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { return 
        malAdapterMoviesList.get(position); }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Movie tempMovie = malAdapterMoviesList.get(position);

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                    .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView mMoviePoster = (ImageView) 
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImageView);
        TextView mMovieTitle = (TextView) 
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieTitle);
        mMovieTitle.setText(tempMovie.getOriginalTitle());

        Picasso
            .with(mContext)
            .load(tempMovie.getImagePosterStr())
            .fit()
            .into(mMoviePoster);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check - In getView function is **tempMovie** object is getting populated or not?
I guess tempMovie object is not getting populated.

Comment: hi Rohan, thank you for your response, and yes, I checked, tempMovie is getting populated... but because the position is stuck at 0, it is just populating the first one.  but i'll look into it again, make sure it is populating correctly, maybe that's why it is stuck at 0.

Comment: @JerryCheng - Yes correct, position value needs to be update.

Comment: how do I update the position value?  isn't it the whole point of the adapter, updates automatically?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what the problem was.  before it was showing a blank screen because when using AsyncTask, the UI is displaying views before the data is loaded.  I found this out when I was debugging, when I'm stepping through the code the views are generated.  So I looked that up and it shows the cause of that is because I need to use onPostExecute to set and load the data into the views when doInBackground is finished